# Which canonical scripture is this sahasranama part of?

Tags: puranas, lakshmi, itihasa, sahasranama

Any Sahasranama is not usually found as an independent hymn/devotional scripture , but as a part of purana , itihasa. etc ,normally traced through its menion in sankalpa vakya(epilogue)(that begins with iti shri).

This is a very famous Mahalakshmi sahasranama( Padmanane Padmakare sarva lokaika Pujithe..)

https://sanskritdocuments.org/doc_devii/lakShmIsahasranAmastotram.html

Which Purana/Itihasa (any canonical scripture)is this sahasranama part of?

Comment: The scanned version source of the Sahasranamam at the Index-extra header opens at archive. Where it says it's found in the Sanatkumar Samhita of the Skanda Purana (Samhita-Version).

Comment: Lakshmi sahasranama , part of sanatkumara samhita,skanda Purana (the other popular version ) seems to differ from this version by the Rishi of the sahasranama. (ananda-kardama-chiklithaendira-suthadhayo)आनन्दकर्दमचिक्लीतेन्दिरासुतादयो महात्मानो maharishayaha, is the Rishi for sanatkumara samhita version. whereas mahavishnur bhagavan rishihi is for the other version. so Iam not sure , whether it could be the part of the same samhita.

Comment: Yes, it's not the same.